# Proof: For any subsequence $a_{n_k}$ Prove $\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n \le \lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k} \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series, proof-verification, proof-writing, real-numbers

> For any convergent subsequence $a_{n_k}$ of  $a_n$, Prove: $$\liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n \le \lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k} \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n.$$

**My attempt**

For this proof it should be noted that ${n_k}>N \subseteq {n}>N$ and thus $a_{{n_k}>N} \subseteq a_{n>N}$} 
$$\text{Let } n\in\mathbb{N}\text{, and }n_k\in\mathbb{N}\text{, and }N > 0$$
    $$\Rightarrow \inf a_{n>N} \le a_{n>N} \le \sup a_{n>N}$$
Since $a_{{n_k}>N}\subseteq a_{n>N}$ and by the definintions of limit superior and limit inferior

$$\Rightarrow \lim_{N\to\infty} \inf a_{n>N} \le \lim_{N\to\infty} a_{{n_k}>N} \le \lim_{N\to\infty} \sup a_{n>N}$$
    $$\Rightarrow \liminf_{n\to\infty} a_n \le \lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k} \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$$

$$\therefore \liminf_{n\to\infty} \le \lim_{k\to\infty} a_{n_k} \le \limsup_{n\to\infty} a_n$$

How far off am I? Is my simplification of the limits okay?

Comment: You are assuming $\lim_ka_{n_k}$ exists.

Comment: @GerryMyerson Sorry, I fixed the question. It actually stated for any convergent subsequent so it should be fine to assume the $\lim_{k}a_{n_k}\exists$